# Iptables : Allowing FTP access only to one host?

Tags: linux, iptables, ftp

I'm totally new to iptables but I need it to allow only ftp access to ftp.mywebsite.com, and refuse the ftp connection to other domain/ip (by closing the port?).

Is this possible? how can I do that?

I googled for it but couldn't find a solution.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -d ftp.mywebsite.com --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 21 -j REJECT
```

If you are not on a firewall system and you want to use the local iptables, it have to look like this:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d ftp.mywebsite.com --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j REJECT
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What do you mean by "not on a firewall system ?" I will use the iptable from my only one server.

Comment: @cx42net You could have a dedicated firewall system / router. In your case, use the second one

Comment: I've got an error when I write the first line of the second solution : "iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.". Do you know why?

Comment: @cx42net make sure you have installed the iptables packages of your distribution and the kernel modules are present. If they are missing, you will get an error like this.

Comment: I checked and it's installed. But from the manual of iptables, there is no "OUTPUT" chain method apparently :/

Comment: @cx42net what distribution do you use? The "OUTPUT" chain must be always there. Have a look with `iptables -L`

Comment: @cx42net let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/685/discussion-between-thomas-berger-and-cx42net)

Comment: Ok, total shame on me! I was writing output in lower case and iptables is case sensitive .... I'm gonna jump in the highway, i'll be back ... :p

Comment: But something's odd : even if I write "ftp.mywebsite.com", the "destination" in iptables -L is "mywebsite.com". And I tested to connect via ftp with "random.mywebsite.com" and it worked :/ (I written the two rules!)